# Accessing static variable value

Tags: c

I have a `static` variable in source file **test_1.c** declared as:

```
static char var1 = 0;
```

I need to access the current value of this variable from source file **test_2.c**. So, I did something like:

In test_1.c

```
static char var1 = 0;
volatile char var_another = var1;
```

and in **test_2.c**, I declare the variable **var_another** as `extern` and access it:

```
extern volatile char var_another;
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Why is it static if you want to access it in another file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static` and `extern` are mutually exclusive. If you want to access your `static char var1` from a different file, you'll have to remove the `static` and just make it a regular global. You don't need `volatile` at all.

Alternatively, you can make an accessor function that returns the value of `static char var1` and use that from your other module.

Side note: externs and exported function prototypes should generally go in header files.

Answer (score 3):

No!  The whole point of `static` (in this context) is that you're stating that the variable is only visible from this translation module.

If you don't want this behaviour, then don't declare it as static.  Put `char var1 = 0;` in your source file, and `extern var1;` in the associated header file.

More generally, don't do this at all.  Accessing global variables between source files is probably a recipe for disaster.