# fork.c:764: request for member `list' in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, data-structures, linux-kernel, kernel

hi there i'm working on a project about compiling kernel. However, i'm facing with an error which says

```
fork.c: In function `do_fork':
fork.c:764: request for member `list' in something not a structure or union
```

brief explanation: i'm using a ready linked list which is defined in kernel for every type of structure.(so i have my own data structure) Moreover, i use pre-defined functions like add,traverse,delete node for my linked list but i can't have any progress because of this error. here you can see the header file which contains my data struct.

```
/* project_header.h> */
#ifndef __LINUX_PROJECT_HEADER_H

#define __LINUX_PROJECT_HEADER_H

#include <linux/linkage.h>
#include <linux/vmalloc.h>
#include <linux/list.h>

#endif

typedef struct node{

        struct list_head list; /* kernel's list structure */
        long int sample_pid;

}NODE;
```

this header file is in location `include/linux` directory.

this is my system call which i will use within my new kernel. and i defined `projectList` globally to use it in other files.

```
#include <linux/sample.h>
#include <linux/project_header.h>

NODE projectList;

asmlinkage void sys_sample(void){

        NODE* temp;

                list_for_each_entry(temp, &projectList.list, list){

                        printk(KERN_INFO "TEMP->PID = %ld\n", temp->project_pid);
                }

        return;
}
```

and i try to use it in `fork.c` which is in `kernel/` directory and here you can see the sample code i add into `fork.c`. On the other hand, i call `projectList` with statement `extern projectList` to refer which was defined in `sample.c`

```
      /* do_fork.c */
      /* do_fork() function */
      #include <linux/project_header.h>
      #include <linux/sample.h>

      extern projectList; // Call variable projectList

      .
      .
      .

      do_fork(parameters..){

     struct task_struct* p;
.
.

     line 759-->NODE* newNode;

     line 760-->newNode = kmalloc(sizeof(*newNode), GFP_KERNEL);

     line 761-->newNode->sample_pid = p->pid;

     line 762-->INIT_LIST_HEAD(&newNode->list);

     /* add the new node to mylist */

     line 764--> list_add_tail(&(newNode->list), &(projectList.list));

     .
     .
     .
    }
```

i hope i been clear to you, i will be very glad if you can help me and thanks anyway

Comment: It's difficult to follow what's in each of your source files.  Can you create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) test-case?

Comment: Not to disturb you, but if you can't resolve a simple compiler error yourself, you should probably not be doing kernel programming yet.

Comment: i tried to be very simple and believe me this is the simplest notation. i can explain that. i have a header file which contains a structure, in my own defined system call i define a type of structure globally and calling it in fork.c with extern prefix

Comment: @quartaela: No it's not.  I'm certain that you don't need 700+ lines of code to cause the problem ;)

Comment: And you haven't pasted real code, here you have `long int sample_pid;` as member, but use `temp->project_pid` and `newNode->project_pid = p->pid;`.

Comment: well i made some edit to make more clear for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
extern projectList; // Call variable projectList
```

You forgot to declare the type of `projectList` here, so if the compiler is in C89 mood, it applies the "implicit `int`" rule. Thus your `projectList` is an `int` in `fork.c`, and not a `struct` or `union` that has members.

Comment: yeah finally it works. i read the use of extern variable from here and it takes hours to recognize it. thanks for your reply :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989607/accessing-static-variable-value